# Flask app gets 404 in Kubernetes through ingress without redirect

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

With the below ingress my app works but if I remove "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1" it does not work and gets a 404 error. If I forward to my local kubectl via port-forward service/hello_service 8080:80 -n hello_world I can access it at http://localhost:8080/. For the ingress I use http://my.example.url/hello_service/. But if I do not include the rewrite the ingress does not work. I thought it would work w/ out because its just hitting the base url and not a url that would need to be rewrote upstream. Is there a way to get the ingress working w/ out the rewrite? Like some settings or configuration I'm missing in the flask app maybe? Or am I totally misunderstanding the ingress and the rewrite and whats going on? There are other apps that work w/ out the rewrite where I would visit the base url just the same so that is what has go me turned my head sideways. Hoping to get some clarification on what might be going on and my various options so I understand this.

This is a basic stripped down example I put together to try to figure it out. The example url I just made up. I have my own url that actually gets used.

Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello_ingress
  namespace: hello_world
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.org/mergeable-ingress-type: "minion"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.example.url
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello_service/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: hello_service
          servicePort: 80
```

Service

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hello_service
  namespace: hello_world
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: hello_world_app
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
```

DockerFile

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 
COPY hello_world.py /usr/src/app
COPY Dockerfile /usr/src/app
RUN pip install flask flask-restplus
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "python3", "hello_world.py"]
```

hello_world.py

```
from flask import Flask
import os
import socket

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World from host \"%s\".\n' % socket.gethostname()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug=True)
enter code here
```

Comment: It's hard to understand (for me at least) what is your goal. Do you want `hello_service` to be available at root `/`?

Comment: I want hello_service to be available at the <url>/hello_service/ via the ingress. In the pod its running at /. When running the flask app locally I can access it at http://localhost:8080. But when I build the docker image that runs it, creates a kubernetes service, and the kubernetes ingress that points to the service I thought it would work as is. Since I thought the ingress points to the base even without the redirect. With the redirect I don't get what its actually doing differently.